# How do I build a tree dynamically in Python

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

A beginner Python/programming question... I'd like to build a tree structure in Python, preferably based on dictionaries. I found code that does this neatly:

```
Tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(Tree)
root = Tree()
```

This can easily be populated like:

```
 root['toplevel']['secondlevel']['thirdlevel'] = 1
 root['toplevel']['anotherLevel'] = 2
 ...etc.
```

I'd like to populate the levels/leaves dynamically so that I can add as many levels as needed, and where the leaves can be at any level. How do I do that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use this code as it is. You can add as many levels as you want. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I don't know how many levels I have beforehand, so I'd like to be able to add them dynamically instead of hardcoding them

Comment: this is recursion man, have you tried my answer? all you have to do is change the object type from the standard object to a dictionary

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of code you'd like to write, or of some input you'd like to process into a tree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do it with a utility function, like this

```
def add_element(root, path, data):
    reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], path[:-1], root)[path[-1]] = data
```

You can use it, like this

```
import collections
tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
root = tree()
add_element(root, ['toplevel', 'secondlevel', 'thirdlevel'], 1)
add_element(root, ['toplevel', 'anotherlevel'], 2)
print root
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f1145eac7d0>,
    {'toplevel': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f1145eac7d0>,
       {'secondlevel': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f1145eac7d0>,
            {'thirdlevel': 1}),
        'anotherlevel': 2
       })
    })
```

If you want to implement this in recursive manner, you can take the first element and get the child object from current `root` and strip the first element from the `path`, for the next iteration.

```
def add_element(root, path, data):
    if len(path) == 1:
        root[path[0]] = data
    else:
        add_element(root[path[0]], path[1:], data)
```

Comment: This helps a lot thanks. But what if I want to build the levels one by one. i.e., I don't really have all pahts beforehand. I want to build the first level, and if I have a child node of that, build another level, ...etc.

Comment: He needs a recursive function man, check the tags in the question, I think he needs guidance as to how to go about building an object tree that goes N levels deep using recursion. you've got 23.4k rep, you're the expert on this

Comment: @pythonian29033 I just managed to give a basic recursive version please check :)

Comment: @user252652 You can use either version to add the elements as and when you get data, as long as you know the `path`.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks, I shoulda prolly changed my answer to be that simple, but at least I got an upvote :D

Answer (score 1):

aah! this was a problem for me when I started coding as well, but the best of us come across this early.

Note; this is for when your tree is going N levels deep. where N is between 0 and infinite, ie; you don't know how deep it can go; it may only have a first level, or it may go up to a 20th level

your problem is a general programming problem; reading in a tree that could be any number of levels deep and the solution to that is; Recursion.

whenever reading in a tree structure, you have to;

1 - build up an object
2 - check whether the object has children
   2a - if the object has children, do steps 1 and 2 for each child.

here's a code template in python for doing this;

```
def buildTree(treeObject):
   currObject = Hierarchy()
   currObject.name = treeObject.getName()
   currObject.age = treeObject.getAge()
   #as well as any other calculations and values you have to set for that object

   for child in treeObject.children:
      currChild = buildTree(child)
      currObject.addChild(currChild)
   #end loop

   return currObject
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
root['toplevel']['secondlevel']['thirdlevel'] = 1
```

can also be done like this:

```
node = root
for key in ('toplevel', 'secondlevel'):
    node = node[key]
node['thirdlevel'] = 1
```

I hope that gives you an idea.