# How to construct a dynamic tree level by level in python?

Tags: python, dynamic, tree

I want to construct a **dynamic tree**. The initial state of the tree only has a root node, then, I hope it can **add nodes level by level**. These added nodes are fetched according to some additional functions. I have found some similary questions in Stack Overflow, such as How do I build a tree dynamically in Python [How do I build a tree dynamically in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328891/how-do-i-build-a-tree-dynamically-in-python),  but the answers don't satisfy my need and the originer.

Comment: Why don't the answers satisfy your need? They literally do what you want?

Comment: beaucse the answers should specify all paths beforehand. I want to build the first level, and if I have a child node of that, build another level, ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

## From the answer of the question

```
import collections
from functools import reduce 

def add_element(root, path, data):
    if len(path) == 1:
        root[path[0]] = data
    else:
        add_element(root[path[0]], path[1:], data)

tree = lambda: collections.defaultdict(tree)
root = tree()

add_element(root,["top"],{}) #Make a level
add_element(root,["top","level1"],{}) # Make another level
add_element(root,["top","level1","val"],2) #Data
print(root)
```

As I mentioned, it does do what you want it to do.